# ionic3 - webservices not working when created the build for android

Tags: ionic-framework

so this morning I finalized one of my app in ionic3 and prepared a build (ionic cordova build android), all went well and I installed the apk in my phone (vivo  Y69). When I tried to login to my webservices, which are written in php-CI, it didn't work. But I am able to login when I run the app on browser (ionic serve) and all the web services are working just fine.

Can anyone have any solution to this?

Comment: share some code.. so that we can understand the actual problem..

Answer (score 0):

install cordova-whitelist-plugin

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

and check whether this line is there in config.xml

```
<access origin="*" />
```

**Try by adding this in config.xml**

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it was CORS issue and after I added into my php file it started working.